# ServiceStack Built In Profiling Without Global.asax

Tags: c#, servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to add profiling to a server running ServiceStack that isn't built with ASP.net.  As far as I can tell, there is no Global.asax file associated with the project.  Instead, it calls Init() and Start(String urlBase) on a subclass of ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostHttpListenerBase

Based on [the ServiceStack Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) there is a profiler built into ServiceStack as ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.  But every use of it says I need to start and stop the profiler in two hooks defined in a Global.asax file.  I don't have one.  Can I still use this profiler?

My closest attempt so far is to try and hook in using the AppHostHttpListenerBase subclass.  I've tried calling Profiler.Start() in a PreRequestFilter and Profiler.Stop() in an override of OnEndRequest, but while these gets called at about the right time, I don't see profiler results being generated when debug stepping through, nor do I see results being displayed in my browser.

Is using this profiler possible in this configuration?  If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mini Profiler depends on `HttpContext.Current` internally and therefore is only available in ASP.NET hosts.